# Select next node after specific condition

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to select the next node value (number 4) after the span tag in the html below.  How can I do that??

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#"> 1 </a></td>
    <td><a href="#"> 2 </a></td>
    <td><span> 3 </span></td>
    <td><a href="#"> 4 </a></td>
    <td><a href="#"> 5 </a></td>
    <td><a href="#"> 6 </a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String html = "<tr valign=\"top\">\n"
        + "    <td></td>\n"
        + "    <td><a href=\"#\"> 1 </a></td>\n"
        + "    <td><a href=\"#\"> 2 </a></td>\n"
        + "    <td><span> 3 </span></td>\n"
        + "    <td><a href=\"#\"> 4 </a></td>\n"
        + "    <td><a href=\"#\"> 5 </a></td>\n"
        + "    <td><a href=\"#\"> 6 </a></td>\n"
        + "</tr>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element nextToSpan = doc.select("span").first().nextElementSibling();
```

**Explained:**

```
doc.select("span") // Select the span-tags of doc
    .first()    // retrieve the first one
    .nextElementSibling();  // Get the element that's next to it
```

**Documentation:** http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax